# Fetching NUTS2 region from geocoordinates and/or postalcode

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a df that contains data including geocoordinates and postcodes.

```
lat     | lon  | postcode
54.3077 | 12.7 | 18314   
51.898  | 9.26 | 32676
```

I need a new colum with the NUTS2 region, so in this case the resulting df should look something like this:

```
lat     | lon  | postcode | NUTS_ID
54.3077 | 12.7 | 18314    | DE80
51.898  | 9.26 | 32676    | DEA4
```

I found this package: https://github.com/vis4/pyshpgeocode which I managed to run. My first approach are the following two functions:

```py
def get_gc(nuts='geoc\\shapes\\nuts2\\nuts2.shp'):
    """
    nuts -> path to nuts file
    """
    gc = geocoder(nuts, filter=lambda r: r['LEVL_CODE'] == 2)
    return gc
```

```py
def add_nuts_to_df(df):
    """
    df must have lon/lat geocoodinates in it
    This function will add a column ['NUTS_ID'] with the corresponding
    NUTS region
    """
    start_time = time.time()
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        df.loc[idx, 'NUTS_ID'] = get_gc().geocode(row.lat,
                                                  row.lon,
              filter=lambda r: r['NUTS_ID'][:2] == 'DE')['NUTS_ID']
        print('Done with index {}\nTime since start: {}s'.format(idx,
              round(time.time() - start_time, 0 )))
    return df
```

And this does work! However, it takes ~ 0.6s for one entry and some of my df have more than a million entries. Since my original dataframes usually contain postcodes I was thinking about aggregating them using a combination of groupby / apply / transform?

Or is there any other (more efficient) way of doing this?

I am very grateful for any help and look forward to receiving replies.

Comment: You are running `get_gc()` for every row (more than a million times). It could be as simple as moving that outside the loop.

Comment: Wow, once again I feel really stupid.
Now each entry needs ~ 0,08s.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly you are re-creating the `gc` object for every single request from the same input file. I don't understand why.

One possibility therefore could be to do the following:

```
def add_nuts_to_df(df):
    """
    df must have lon/lat geocoodinates in it
    This function will add a column ['NUTS_ID'] with the corresponding
    NUTS region
    """
    nuts='geoc\\shapes\\nuts2\\nuts2.shp'
    gc = geocoder(nuts, filter=lambda r: r['LEVL_CODE'] == 2)

    start_time = time.time()
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        df.loc[idx, 'NUTS_ID'] = gc.geocode(row.lat,
                                                  row.lon,
              filter=lambda r: r['NUTS_ID'][:2] == 'DE')['NUTS_ID']
        print('Done with index {}\nTime since start: {}s'.format(idx,
              round(time.time() - start_time, 0 )))
    return df
```

Maybe it would speed up the process even more if you try to use the `df.apply()` method and pass your geocode logic in a function there.

Something like:

```
nuts='geoc\\shapes\\nuts2\\nuts2.shp'
gc = geocoder(nuts, filter=lambda r: r['LEVL_CODE'] == 2)

def get_nuts_id(row):
    return gc.geocode(row.lat, row.lon, 
                      filter=lambda r: r['NUTS_ID'][:2] == 'DE')['NUTS_ID']

df["NUTS_ID"] = df.apply(get_nuts_id,axis=1)
```

I didn't try this out though so beware of typos.

Comment: Ok, this is pretty awesome. I tried it with a df with 1000 entries and it returned almost instantly! Thank you very much!